# Need to know about the usage of #if in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am using C#. Need to know about the usage of #if.
The code details is:

```
#if
    //logic code
#else
    //logic code
#endif
    //logic code
```

I cant understand how its working in  debugging mode.
Waiting for quick response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could easily answer this with a quick internet search....

Comment: @Pauli very nice link ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"#if DEBUG" works because Visual Studio creates a Pre-processor directive with the name DEBUG based on current Solution's configuration(either in Release Mode or Debug Mode) - Solution configuration have option to enable/disable DEBUG and TRACE constants and to associate them with solution configurations.

You can use this directive anywhere in code and it help eliminating code based on mode at build time. and this is really a common scenario where some times we need a code to run only in debug mode but not in release mode. more details you can find here

http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/05/determine-debug-mode-in-net.html

Regards,

**Edit:** Thanks to Paul Alexander for clarification

Comment: To clarify, the `DEBUG` constant is not actually defined automatically just by selecting Debug/Release configurations. You must still define it in your project's build settings. By default when a new project is created, the DEBUG option is selected. However if it is unselected it will remain unselected even if you select the Debug build configuration. Earlier versions of Visual Studio didn't even define it at all.

Comment: thnx for the further clarification. i though it is purely based on solution configuration. but we can set it from solution configuration settings because it is customizable.

Answer (score 6):

C# defines several preprocessor directives, which affect the way that your program’s source
file is interpreted by the compiler. These directives affect the text of the source file in which
they occur, prior to the translation of the program into object code. The term preprocessor
directive comes from the fact that these instructions were traditionally handled by a separate
compilation phase called the preprocessor. Today’s modern compiler technology no longer
requires a separate preprocessing stage to handle the directives, but the name has stuck.

The `#define` directive defines a character sequence called a symbol. The existence or nonexistence
of a symbol can be determined by `#if` or `#elif`, and is used to control compilation.

The #if and #endif directives allow you to conditionally compile a sequence of code based
upon whether an expression involving one or more symbols evaluates to true. A symbol is true
if it has been defined. It is false otherwise. Thus, if a symbol has been defined by a `#define`
directive, it will evaluate as true.
The general form of #if is

```
#if symbol-expression
statement sequence
#endif
```

If the expression following #if is true, the code that is between it and `#endif` is compiled.
Otherwise, the intervening code is skipped. The `#endif` directive marks the end of an #if block.
A symbol expression can be as simple as just the name of a symbol. You can also use these
operators in a symbol expression: `!`, `==`, `!=`, `&&`, and `||`. Parentheses are also allowed.

**C# 3.0 A Beginner's Guide By Herbert Schildt**(the best book for learning C# IMO)

Answer (score 4):

Its basically telling the compiler what parts of code you either want or not want to be included based on some symbol being defined.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

When the C# compiler encounters an #if directive, followed eventually by an #endif directive, it will compile the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined. Unlike C and C++, you cannot assign a numeric value to a symbol; the #if statement in C# is Boolean and only tests whether the symbol has been defined or not.